# MongoDB to manage model User and model Image like relationships or another db alternative like neo4j to handle this

Tags: database, mongodb, neo4j

I am currently using MongoDB as my database and ran into an architecture related question. I have the model User and the model Image, users can like and unlike images. I want an Image to able to get a 1000 likes if not 100,000 likes and thus the user and image like relationships need to be monitored and updated efficiently.

Just using mongodb i could do the below setup but i think this would cause issues after 1000 likes

Image Model:
- name
- url
- likeCount (number)
- likes (array to track liked users)

I dont think this is very efficient or scalable so Im thinking of using neo4j specifically as another db layer to manage large relationships. I am not sure if adding another db is the best approach to this and was hoping to open a discussion here and get feedback on how to address this scaling issue

Comment: Im going to give this a go: https://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/

Comment: Use Image Model: name, url, createduser:(_id of User from User model), likeduser:[array of ObjectId], dislikeduser:[array of ObjectId] if user likes the image add the user's '_id' to likeduser and viceversa, so getting the likeduser array size or dislikeduser arraysize u will get the count.